# Executing aws cli using php in windows - error unknown encoding

Tags: php, aws-cli

Trying to invoke the aws cli from php, but a simple test `shell_exec('aws help');` will result in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws", line 27, in <module>
  File "aws", line 23, in main
  File "awscli\clidriver.pyc", line 59, in main
  File "awscli\clidriver.pyc", line 197, in main
  File "awscli\argparser.pyc", line 100, in parse_known_args
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001
```

It works perfectly fine when running directly in command-window (cmd.exe).

Python version:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

For some reason shell_exec is defaulting to use utf8 / cp65001...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution after trying to set different locale config and php settings.

A call to `chcp` before any `shell_exec` solved it!

```
exec("chcp 850");
```